# How to map abstract class result in MyBatis?

Tags: java, abstract-class, mybatis

Here are my classes:

```java
@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
public class UtilityDetails {
  private final int id;
  private final string name;
  private final LocalDateTime createdAt;
  private final boolean archived;
  private final int sortOrder;

  private final TariffDetails currentTariff;
}

@RegisterForReflection
public abstract sealed class TariffDetails
    permits TariffDualRateDetails,
    TariffSingleRateDetails,
    TariffSubscriptionDetails {

  public abstract TariffId getId();
  public abstract UtilityId getUtilityId();
  public abstract LocalDateTime getCreatedAt();
}

@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
public final class TariffDualRateDetails extends TariffDetails {
    private final int id;
    private final int utilityId;
    private final LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private final long threshold;
    private final int unitSize;
    private final long priceBelowThreshold;
    private final long priceAboveThreshold;
    private final ThresholdComparison thresholdComparison;
}

public enum ThresholdComparison {
  LESS_EQUALS,
  STRICT_LESS;
}

@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
public final class TariffSingleRateDetails extends TariffDetails {
    private final int id;
    private final int utilityId;
    private final LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private final long price;
    private final int unitSize;
}

@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
public final class TariffSubscriptionDetails extends TariffDetails {
    private final int id;
    private final int utilityId;
    private final LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private final long price;
}
```

Here is my mapper:

```xml
    <select id="getUtilityDetailsById" resultMap="utilityDetails">
        select u.id                      as u_id,
               u.name                    as u_name,
               u.created_at              as u_created_at,
               u.archived                as u_archived,
               u.sort_order              as u_sort_order,
               t.id                      as t_id,
               t.created_at              as t_created_at,
               case
                   when tdr.tariff_id is not null then 'DUAL_RATE'
                   when tsr.tariff_id is not null then 'SINGLE_RATE'
                   when ts.tariff_id is not null then 'SUBSCRIPTION'
                   end                   as tariff_type,
               tdr.threshold             as tdr_threshold,
               tdr.unit_size             as tdr_unit_size,
               tdr.threshold_comparison  as tdr_threshold_comparison,
               tdr.price_above_threshold as tdr_price_above_threshold,
               tdr.price_below_threshold as tdr_price_below_threshold,
               tsr.unit_size             as tsr_unit_size,
               tsr.price                 as tsr_price,
               ts.price                  as ts_price

        from utility u
                 inner join tariff t on u.id = t.utility_id
                 left join tariff_dual_rate tdr on t.id = tdr.tariff_id
                 left join tariff_single_rate tsr on t.id = tsr.tariff_id
                 left join tariff_subscription ts on t.id = ts.tariff_id
        order by t.created_at desc
        limit 1
    </select>

    <resultMap id="utilityDetails" type="org.upc.model.UtilityDetails">
        <constructor>
            <idArg name="id" column="u_id"/>
            <arg name="name" column="u_name"/>
            <arg name="createdAt" column="u_created_at"/>
            <arg name="archived" column="u_archived"/>
            <arg name="sortOrder" column="u_sort_order"/>
            <arg name="currentTariff" resultMap="tariffMap"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tariffDualRate" type="org.upc.model.TariffDualRateDetails" extends="tariffMap">
        <constructor>
            <idArg name="id" column="t_id"/>
            <arg name="utilityId" column="u_id"/>
            <arg name="createdAt" column="t_created_at"/>
            <arg name="threshold" column="tdr_threshold"/>
            <arg name="unitSize" column="tdr_unit_size"/>
            <arg name="thresholdComparison" column="tdr_threshold_comparison"/>
            <arg name="priceAboveThreshold" column="tdr_price_above_threshold"/>
            <arg name="priceBelowThreshold" column="tdr_price_below_threshold"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tariffSingleRate" type="org.upc.model.TariffSingleRateDetails" extends="tariffMap">
        <constructor>
            <idArg name="id" column="t_id"/>
            <arg name="utilityId" column="u_id"/>
            <arg name="createdAt" column="t_created_at"/>
            <arg name="price" column="tsr_price"/>
            <arg name="unitSize" column="tsr_unit_size"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tariffSubscription" type="org.upc.model.TariffSubscriptionDetails" extends="tariffMap">
        <constructor>
            <idArg name="id" column="t_id"/>
            <arg name="utilityId" column="u_id"/>
            <arg name="createdAt" column="t_created_at"/>
            <arg name="price" column="ts_price"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>

    <resultMap id="tariffMap" type="org.upc.model.TariffDetails">
        <discriminator javaType="string" column="tariff_type">
            <case value="DUAL_RATE" resultMap="tariffDualRate"/>
            <case value="SINGLE_RATE" resultMap="tariffSingleRate"/>
            <case value="SUBSCRIPTION" resultMap="tariffSubscription"/>
        </discriminator>
    </resultMap>
```

For some reason it tries to instantiate that abstract class `TariffDetails` and fails, because it's, well, an abstract class:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class org.upc.model.TariffDetails with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
### The error may exist in org/upc/repository/UtilityRepository.xml
### The error may involve org.upc.repository.UtilityRepository.getUtilityDetailsById
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: select u.id                      as u_id,                u.name                    as u_name,                u.created_at              as u_created_at,                u.archived                as u_archived,                u.sort_order              as u_sort_order,                t.id                      as t_id,                t.created_at              as t_created_at,                case                    when tdr.tariff_id is not null then 'DUAL_RATE'                    when tsr.tariff_id is not null then 'SINGLE_RATE'                    when ts.tariff_id is not null then 'SUBSCRIPTION'                    end                   as tariff_type,                tdr.threshold             as tdr_threshold,                tdr.unit_size             as tdr_unit_size,                tdr.threshold_comparison  as tdr_threshold_comparison,                tdr.price_above_threshold as tdr_price_above_threshold,                tdr.price_below_threshold as tdr_price_below_threshold,                tsr.unit_size             as tsr_unit_size,                tsr.price                 as tsr_price,                ts.price                  as ts_price          from utility u                  inner join tariff t on u.id = t.utility_id                  left join tariff_dual_rate tdr on t.id = tdr.tariff_id                  left join tariff_single_rate tsr on t.id = tsr.tariff_id                  left join tariff_subscription ts on t.id = ts.tariff_id         order by t.created_at desc         limit 1
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class org.upc.model.TariffDetails with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:153)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:145)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at io.quarkiverse.mybatis.runtime.TransactionalSqlSession$TransactionalSqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionalSqlSession.java:197)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy55.selectOne(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkiverse.mybatis.runtime.TransactionalSqlSession.selectOne(TransactionalSqlSession.java:46)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:87)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy62.getUtilityDetailsById(Unknown Source)
    at org.upc.services.UtilityService.getUtilityDetailsById(UtilityService.java:38)
    at org.upc.services.UtilityService_ClientProxy.getUtilityDetailsById(Unknown Source)
    at org.upc.resources.UtilityResource.getUtilityDetailsById(UtilityResource.java:35)
    at org.upc.resources.UtilityResource$quarkusrestinvoker$getUtilityDetailsById_24450c22d8569dcc4e8cbc86dde64aa8cf8ba2ac.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class org.upc.model.TariffDetails with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:667)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:642)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:404)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createParameterizedResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:686)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:665)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:642)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:432)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForNestedResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:988)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:333)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:308)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:201)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:151)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:62)
    ... 47 more
```

How do I make it instantiate a correct child class?

Comment: It seems that `<discriminator>` does not work in constructor mapping at the moment (version 3.5.13). Could you open a new issue on the [tracker](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/new) with the details? If you are busy, I'll do it when I find the time.

Comment: @ave, if you can, please do it

Comment: Here is the [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/2913) and the fix has been committed. It would be great if you could verify the fix using the [3.5.14-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/Maven#snapshot) before we release the final version.